# Trying to install Symfony 2.3 but it keeps installing 2.4

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm creating a project that is going to be around for a long time, so I like the look of Symfony 2.3 LTS.

I did this in Composer, but it installed 2.4.2 instead:

```
php composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.3.12
```

I then checked the composer.json and saw:

```
"symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
```

I changed that to 2.3 and ran an update but all sorts of errors prevented me.

How do I install 2.3 LTS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple mistake: you're adding 2.3.12 as the path to create the project in, not the version constraint. Try this command:

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition /path/to/project 2.3.*
```